Log.Information not printing log message, despite threshold set to debug
I have an Azure Function, which I struggle to get to log information to the console, when running in debug. I believe I have configured it correctly in local.settings.json. You can see the content of my file here:
local.settings.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Error"
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": true
    }
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "..."
  }
}

I am testing it by having these three log statements a place in the code, which I know is executed:
Code inside the function
_logger.LogInformation("+++TESTING INFORMATION LOGGING+++");
_logger.LogWarning("+++TESTING WARNING LOGGING+++");
_logger.LogError("+++TESTING ERROR LOGGING+++");

The last two are printing correctly to the console, but there is no trace of the LogInformation statement.
Now if I reduce the threshold in my host.json file to Information (or lower) it starts showing as intended. But shouldn't local.settings.json take precedence over this?
I am not doing anything manually to add either of these files, but the function is using appsettings.json and Azure Key Vault, if that can have any effect. The setup is as following:
Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        configBuilder
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                optional: false,
                reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(configBuilder.Build()["KeyVaultUrl"]), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        ConfigureServices(services, hostContext.Configuration);
    })
    .Build();


Do you have any logging properties in the "appsettings.{Environment}.json" file or in the KeyVault?

No, none at all. Only other stuff.

It turns out that host.json isn't simple overridden by having the same values in local.settings.json, at least not when it comes to logging.
Instead you can do something like this, to override it, but it will be a bit cumbersome, if you need to override too many values:
{
    (...),
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{storage-account-connection-string}",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "{language-runtime}",
        "AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__default":"Debug" // This will override host.json
    }
}

For more information see the documentation.
